# Checking the value from given threshold in a set of observation and continue till end of vector

Tags: r

Task:

1. I have to check that if the value in the data vector is above from the given threshold,
2. If in my data vector, I found 5 consecutive values greater then the given threshold then I keep these values as they are.
3. If I have less then 5 values (not 5 consecutive values) then I will replace these values with `NA`'s.

The sample data and required output is shown below. In this example the threshold value is `1000`. `X` is input data variable and the desired output is: Y = X(Threshold > 1000)

```
  X      Y
 580   580 
 457   457 
 980   980 
1250    NA 
3600    NA 
 598   598 
1200  1200 
1345  1345 
9658  9658 
1253  1253 
4500  4500
1150  1150 
 596   596 
 594   594
 550   550 
1450    NA 
 320   320 
1780    NA 
 592   592 
 590   590
```

I have used the following code in R for my desired output but unable to get the appropriate one:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(X)) # X is my data vector
{counter=0  
if (X[i]>10000)
{
    for (j in i:(i+4))
    { 
       if (X[j]>10000) 
        {counter=counter+1}

    }
    ifelse (counter < 5, NA, X[j])

    }
    X[i]<- NA
}
X
```

I am sure that the above code contain some error. I need help in the form of either a new code or modifying this code or any package in R.

Comment: Is X a column in a data frame (let's call it 'df' as an example)? Or a vector? In the first case you should index X in the loop as df$X[i] or df$X[j]. Otherwise, if X is just a vector, then norw(X) is always NULL and you should use length(X) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using dplyr, using a cumulative sum of `diff(x > 1000)` to group the values.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x)
df

# x
# 1   580
# 2   457
# 3   980
# 4  1250
# 5  3600
# 6   598
# 7  1200
# 8  1345
# 9  9658
# 10 1253
# 11 4500
# 12 1150
# 13  596
# 14  594
# 15  550
# 16 1450
# 17  320
# 18 1780
# 19  592
# 20  590

df %>% mutate(group = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(x>1000))))) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(count = n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(y = ifelse(x<1000 | count > 5, x, NA))

# x group count     y
# (int) (dbl) (int) (int)
# 1    580     0     3   580
# 2    457     0     3   457
# 3    980     0     3   980
# 4   1250     1     2    NA
# 5   3600     1     2    NA
# 6    598     2     1   598
# 7   1200     3     6  1200
# 8   1345     3     6  1345
# 9   9658     3     6  9658
# 10  1253     3     6  1253
# 11  4500     3     6  4500
# 12  1150     3     6  1150
# 13   596     4     3   596
# 14   594     4     3   594
# 15   550     4     3   550
# 16  1450     5     1    NA
# 17   320     6     1   320
# 18  1780     7     1    NA
# 19   592     8     2   592
# 20   590     8     2   590
```

Comment: After running the above set of commands under package "dplyr", I got the following error message: Error in n() : This function should not be called directly.... Could you help me please in solving this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :

```
Y<-rep(NA,nrow(X))
for (i in 1:nrow(X)) {
    if (X[i,1]<1000) {Y[i]<-X[i,1]} else if (sum(X[i:min((i+4),nrow(X)),1]>1000)>=5) {
     Y[i:min((i+4),nrow(X))]<-X[i:min((i+4),nrow(X)),1]} 
}
```

returns

```
> Y
 [1]  580  457  980   NA   NA  598 1200 1345 9658 1253 4500 1150  596  594  550   NA  320   NA  592  590
```

This assumes that the values of X are in the first column of a dataframe named X.
It then creates Y with `NA`and only change the values if the criteria are met.